# How do separable states equate to energy eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's say I have some state vector $|\Psi(t)\rangle$, and I express it as a linear combination of eigenstates of some operator, $\hat{Q}$, with a discrete spectrum, which we will call $|q_n\rangle$. Let's say that $\hat{Q}$ is **not** the Hamiltonian, so these are not energy eigenstates. Then, I have:

$$|\Psi(t)\rangle \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} |q_n\rangle \langle q_n |\Psi(t)\rangle \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} r_n(t) |q_n\rangle$$

Now, if I express this in the position basis, I get something like:

$$\Psi(x,\,t) \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$$

Now each term of this sum is orthogonal, so they obey the Schrödinger Equation. But isn't it true that the wavefunctions that are separable are equivalent to the set of energy eigenfunctions with time dependence? How can this be reconciled with the fact that $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ is a separable wavefunction that is not an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian?

I'm probably making a stupid assumption/mistake somewhere in my reasoning, so any clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: But your wavefunction is $\Psi(x,t)$, not $r_n(t)\psi_n(x)$?

Comment: Yeah, but each term of the sum should obey the Schrödinger equation right?

Comment: If the $\psi_n(x)$ set is orthogonal

Comment: Yes they should. Obeying the Schrodinger equation does not mean energy eigenstate though. A superposition of eigenstates of an operator is not necessarily an eigenstate itself.

Comment: Yes, but aren't the set of separable solutions and the set of energy eigenfunctions the same thing? I shouldn't be able to construct a separable solution like $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ such that it is a solution to the Schrodinger equation and not an energy eigenstate, right?

Comment: I would have to think about that. What I am saying is that your wavefunction is not $r_n(t)\psi_n(x)$, unless you are looking only at an eigenstate of $Q$. Also just because $Q\neq H$ does not mean the eigenstates of $Q$ are not eigenstates of $H$

Comment: Yeah, it is not the general wavefunction $\Psi(x, \ t)$, but to my understanding, it is **a** wavefunction that should obey the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by separable solution?

Comment: Something that can be separated into distinguishable time-dependent and time-independent components, something of the form $\phi(t) \psi(x)$.

Comment: This all originates from the fact that in Griffiths QM, he assumes a separable wavefunction ansatz, then solves the Schrödinger equation to demonstrate separable solutions are the energy eigenstates.

Comment: The incorrect step in your reasoning is "Now each term of this sum is orthogonal, so they obey the Schrödinger Equation." I see no reason why the second claim would follow from the first claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any separable solution to the Schrodinger equation is stationary. The mistaken step in your reasoning is "Each term of this sum is orthogonal, so they obey the Schrödinger Equation." That's not true.

If $Q$ commutes with the Hamiltonian (and there's no degeneracy), then $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ is a stationary state. If $Q$ does not commute with the Hamiltonian, then $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ does not solve the Schrodinger equation. In no situation is $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ a non-stationary separable solution to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: Except the state vector $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ obeys the Schrödinger equation, I'm just expressing it as an expansion in the $\hat{Q}$ basis. Since $\hat{Q}$ is an observable, shouldn't it form a complete orthogonal basis? Thus, if $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ obeys the Schrödinger equation, then so should each term.

Comment: @Jack Yes, $|\psi(t)\rangle$ solves the Schrodinger equation, and yes, the eigenvectors of Q form a complete orthogonal basis, but no, there's no reason why the individual terms in the expansion should each solve the Schrodinger equation. You keep repeating that claim without proving any reasoning for it, but it's not true.

Comment: @JackCeroni I apologize if I sound rude, but you appear to be fundamentally confused about what the term "orthogonal" means. $E \psi_n(x)$ is definitely not orthogonal to $\psi_n(x)$, nor does orthogonality have *anything* to do with solving the Schrodinger equation. Respectfully, I think that you may be better off speaking in person with someone knowledgeable about QM.

Comment: Sorry, that was a really stupid comment, I don’t know why I said that $\psi_n(x)$ is orthogonal to $E\psi_n(x)$, quite the opposite actually.

Comment: It is not the notion of orthogonality that is confusing me, that was just a dumb comment. What I'm trying to clarify is that $\psi_n(x)$ and $\hat{H} \psi_n(x)$ are not scaled versions of the same vector, thus we can't always ensure that $c_n(t)$ is exclusively a coefficient on its corresponding eigenvector $|\psi_n(x)\rangle$ when we apply the Hamiltonian operator, thus we lose the condition of separability, and therefore each of our individual states are not solutions to the Schrödinger equation. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jack If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to say, then yes, that's correct.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help, sorry about the previous confusion, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that comment

Answer (score 0):

The issue is either in the explicit time dependence you have assumed or in thinking your general $\Psi(x,t)$ is separable.

First, let's consider the case where your quantum state is an eigenstate of $Q$:
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle=|q_n\rangle$$

The eigenstates $|q_n\rangle$ should be constant in time (I am assuming). But you are assuming an explicit time dependence on the left-hand side. Therefore, there is no contradiction for your separable state assumption in this case, because $r_n(t)=1$. The state is not an energy eigenstate, as assumed.

Moving to the more general case
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\sum_n|q_n\rangle\langle q_n|\Psi(t)\rangle\to\Psi(x,t)=\sum_nr_n(t)\psi_n(x)$$

Your wavefunction is not separable. i.e.
$$\Psi(x,t)\neq R(t)\psi(x)$$

So in this case there is still not a contradiction. Your state is not an energy eigenstate, as assumed.

> I guess the root of my question is: Is $r_n(t)\psi_n(x)$ a separable solution to the Schrodinger equation that is not an energy eigenstate?

I am still thinking through this. Of course, if it was a separable solution then we would have a contradiction, as you have seen and as @tparker says in their answer. But I cannot think of a proof that does not involve a contradiction at the moment. I feel like it should be something simple that I am just not seeing for some reason.

Although I will say if two functions $A$ and $B$ each solve a linear differential equation $DA=0$ and $DB=0$ then it is true that the sum solves the differential equation: $D(A+B)=0$. However, the converse is not necessarily true. If we know that $D(A+B)=0$, then all we can say is $DA=-DB$, but it is not necessarily true that $DA=DB=0$. For even more terms in the sum we can say the same thing. i.e. if $D\left(\sum_n\Psi_n\right)=0$ it does not necessarily mean that $D\Psi_n=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ok, but even if $R(t)\psi(x)$ isn’t my general wave function, isn’t it still a solution to the Schrödinger equation? Consider the case where I express same state vector as a linear combo of energy eigenstates: $|\Psi(t)\rangle = \sum c_n(t) |E_n\rangle$. Each term in the sum should obey the Schrodinger equation, since the energy eigenstates form an orthogonal basis, which they do, and in the position basis the terms are separable solutions to the Schrodiger equation. How can this not be the case for the $\hat{Q}$ eigenstates?

Comment: @JackCeroni Being a solution to the SE does not mean energy eigenstate. Or maybe I am still not understanding your point

Comment: Yeah I know. The point is that when we solve the Schrodinger equation for the energy eigenstates, we find that $c_n(t) = c_n(0) e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}$ If the above is true, then we should be able to determine that the $r_n(t)$ coefficients are of the same form, which shouldn’t be true

Comment: I guess the root of my question is: Is $r_n(t) \psi_n(x)$ a separable solution to the Schrodinger equation that is not an energy eigenstate?

Comment: @JackCeroni I will think about it and let you know when I have edited

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: @JackCeroni I cannot think of a good explanation still, but I have undeleted my answer to be critiqued by others.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: That wasn't me, I don't know who did it

Comment: @JackCeroni See my edit. I think it pertains to your most recent comment on tparker's answer.

Comment: Yep, I think that clears things up. For some reason, I was thinking that we could separate by just "matching up" the time-dependent components, which is obviously not the case

Comment: In the case of the energy basis, we can do this because each of the wavefunctions in the sum is orthogonal to all the others, thus it must be the case that the term "match up".

Comment: Well, I feel extraordinarily stupid for not seeing this sooner, but this makes complete sense now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @JackCeroni Please upvote all useful answers, and select one answer as the accepted answer for future readers.

Comment: I just have one more question. For the case that $|\Psi(t)\rangle = |q_n\rangle$ for any arbitrary operator $Q$, this is not a solution to the Schrödinger equation, right?

Comment: The reason I ask is because you discuss this case in the first part of your answer, and I wasn’t totally clear on what you meant.

Comment: @JackCeroni What I meant was that the eigenstates of the operator $Q$ shouldn't have time dependence (in general they can, but typically not). So $|\Psi(t)\rangle=|q_n\rangle$ cannot actually have any explicit time dependence. i.e. $\Psi\neq r(t)\psi(x)$

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but $|q_n\rangle$ with no time dependence doesn’t satisfy the Schrödinger equation right off the bat, so why do we even have to consider it?

Comment: @JackCeroni It is the mathematician in me I suppose :)

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, I get where you’re coming from! Just to be perfectly clear, $|q_n\rangle$ is always an unphysical state when it is by itself right? I don’t see how it could satisfy the Schrödinger equation with no time dependence

Answer (score -1):

If the wavefunction can be written as a product of a time-only and a time-independent(say position dependent) component, then every position will evolve the same way which is how energy eigenstates work.

You seem to prove for an arbitrary basis that it is an energy eigenstate basis, but only because of a mistake, I think.

You seem to have confused the abstract vector with the vector components. If you have abstract vectors $|\Psi\rangle $ , $|\Phi\rangle $ you can take the "abstract" inner product which is $\langle \Psi | \Phi \rangle$, but if you want to calculate with these vectors usefully it is useful to express them in a basis (e.g. the eigenvector basis of $\hat{Q}$). This is exactly analogous to regular vectors in 2D space. Now if you want to do any calculation on these vector you have to express them in the same basis!

You calculate the n vector components of abstract vector $|\Psi(t)\rangle \ $ which are $r_n(t)$ this is correct. In other words you expressed it in $\hat{Q}$ eigenvector basis. Now if you want to express $| \Psi(t) \rangle$ in position eigenstate basis (also known as position space), the rule is the same you take the inner product of the vector or its components with all the position eigenstates $|\psi^{[x]} \rangle$. You can do it with the abstract vector and you get $\displaystyle\sum_{x} |\psi^{[x]} \rangle \langle\psi^{[x]} | \Psi(t) \rangle$ or you can take the inner product using its known components in the $\hat{Q}$ eigenvector basis, **but careful, in this case you have to express the position eigenfunctions in the $\hat{Q}$ basis too!** While the position eigenvectors are simple Dirac delta functions in the position basis(any basis is just a bunch of deltas expressed in its on basis), in general the position basisvectors depend on space and time when expressed in any other basis. (as you probably know the position eigenvectors are Dirac deltas in their own basis and infinite waves in the momentum basis and vica-versa).

So you have to express your position eigenvectors(you have one fore each x) in in $\hat{Q}$ first: 
$$|\psi^{[x]}\rangle \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} |q_n\rangle \langle q_n |\psi^{[x]}\rangle \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} {\psi^{[x]}}_n|q_n\rangle$$

Then express in position basis (using Q-based components of the vectors) $$\Psi(x,t):=r^{[x]}(t) = \displaystyle\sum_{n} r_n(t){\psi^{[x]}}_n(t) $$

Now $r^{[x]}$(t) is just a complex number corresponding to every position eigenvector at every time t so we could rename it as just $\Psi(x,t)$ which is what we were looking for.

**summary:**

1. When you calculate vectors you have to be in the same basis or no base at all.
2. Position eigenvectors are time independent only in position eigenbase.

**Update: Expressing a state vector in position basis**

The wrong way to think about it is this: A state vector is like a little arrow and you can take the its inner product with *the* position basis *vector* and you get its x component.

But this is not what state vectors are. State vectors(or wavefunctions if expressed in position basis) can generally have a distinct value at *every* possible x position. A wave function $\Psi(x,t)$ of a single particle for example can be $1/\sqrt(2)$ at x=13 and x=19+$\pi$ and zero everywhere else. This is still just one state vector/wavefunction. Think of the state vector as a "vector" that has a unique value at every single x position. To describe it fully you need not just one x coordinate but one value(amplitude) for every possible x coordinates. (So just a particle in one dimension is an infinite dimensional state vector.).

To write the state vector in position basis you can't just ask what is the length in the x direction. You have to ask what is the amplitude at x=-1 , x=3, x=$\pi$ all of those. How do you do it? Simple! We have a basis vector for each of those $|\psi_{-1}\rangle $, $|\psi_3\rangle $, $|\psi_\pi \rangle $
etc. You take the value inner product with each of the infinite set of position basis vectors.

e.g.:

$$|\Psi \rangle = \displaystyle\sum_x |\psi_x\rangle \langle \psi_x | \Psi \rangle = \displaystyle\sum_x \Psi_x |\psi_x\rangle = \displaystyle\sum_x \Psi(x) |\psi_x\rangle $$

where $\Psi(x)$ is the amplitude(value) of $|\Psi\rangle $ statevectors at x.

Comment: But the OP in the question just does $$\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle=\langle x|\left(\sum_n r_n(t)|q_b\rangle\right)=\sum_n r_n(t)\psi_n(x)$$ where $\langle x|q_n\rangle=\psi_n(x)$. I don't see the issue with that.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Aaron’s comment, I still don’t really understand what is wrong with expanding in the position basis, by taking the inner product with the position bra

Comment: Excellent, It just occurred to me that you might be thinking that way. I write a small update to address that. Thanks for the comments

Comment: Ok, so then we have for out state vector $$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\int|x'\rangle\langle x'|\Psi(t)\rangle\,\text dx'$$ as well as $$|\Psi(t)\rangle=\sum_n|q_n\rangle\langle q_n|\Psi(t)\rangle$$ which means we also have $$\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle=\langle x|\left(\int|x'\rangle\langle x'|\Psi(t)\rangle\,\text dx'\right)=\Psi(x,t)$$ as well as $$\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle=\langle x|\left(\sum_n|q_n\rangle\langle q_n|\Psi(t)\rangle\right)=\sum_nr_n(t)\psi_n(x)$$ so then $$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_nr_n(t)\psi_n(x)$$ so there is still no issue. You keep looking for an error in the OP's work, but I don't think there is

Comment: I think tn the first line you ment to to use integrate by dx' not dt.

Here's the thing: I am not saying you have to write the state in position eigenbasis and then take the inner product with a |x> state vector.

Comment: Well certainly you don't need to do any of this at all. But it is what the OP is asking about, and their math checks out. It is the interpretation of the results that should be questioned. Also please refresh the page to see edits to my comment.

Comment: Can you please state what you think you are doing when you take the inner product of |$\Psi(t)$> with |x> . what do you think the |x> vector is?

Comment: $|x\rangle$ is a position eigenstate. $\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle$ is "picking out" the "position component" of $|\Psi(t)\rangle$. i.e. $\langle x|\Psi(t)\rangle=\Psi(x,t)$ You get a "component" for each $x$ value.